# Is it Islamic belief "Hate the sin, not the sinner"?

Tags: sin, belief, imaan

or is there something else that is opposite or similar to it...

From all the teachings i have received the rule I'd say is Islamic is do what's the best. Basically people change so labelling someone as sinner may make us overlook his/her good parts and overlook their change if it occurs.

Please provide hadiths/Quran if possible

Comment: Yes, otherwise we would have to hate almost everyone.

Answer (score 3):

“Hate the sin, not the sinner” is only partly correct in Islam. Only a sinner with sins wholly occupying his heart making his heart dark lacking any light spot survived in it is one we should hate and even curse against them, though, if we can identify them correctly. About any other sinner no we cannot hate himself, but we must hate the sin, and the majority of the sinners belong to this latter group. The former group are those who would be left in the hell eternally, the rest will be survived from the hell and let enter the heaven after centuries and maybe millenniums or more of being tortured in the hell.

Those with completely dark hearts will never find the opportunity to repent in Dunya (world), they are Taqut (طاغوت: or leaders inviting to the Fire: أَئِمَّةً يَدْعُونَ إِلَى النَّارِ‌, Al-Qasas,41) against which Allah has ordered us to be Kafir about them. The others we should always have hope that they may repent, and we should help them so by enjoying them to what is right and banning them from what s wrong.

> اللَّـهُ وَلِيُّ الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا يُخْرِ‌جُهُم مِّنَ الظُّلُمَاتِ
>   إِلَى النُّورِ‌ ۖ وَالَّذِينَ كَفَرُ‌وا أَوْلِيَاؤُهُمُ الطَّاغُوتُ
>   يُخْرِ‌جُونَهُم مِّنَ النُّورِ‌ إِلَى الظُّلُمَاتِ ۗ أُولَـٰئِكَ
>   أَصْحَابُ النَّارِ‌ ۖ هُمْ فِيهَا خَالِدُونَ
>
> Allah is the ally of those who believe. He brings them out from
>   darknesses into the light. And those who disbelieve - their allies are
>   Taghut. They take them out of the light into darknesses. Those are the
>   companions of the Fire; they will abide eternally therein.
>   [Al-Baqareh, 257]

Godspeed

Comment: You speak as if there is virtue in hating and cursing. Unless you can provide references to support the ideas of "hating and cursing" and that there are some for whom "doors of salvation" are closed much before their death - you answer remains dogmatic.

Comment: Beautiful Answer. Shows how practical Islam is!

Comment: @user549, cf e.g. Albaqrah/159 which reads "إِنَّ الَّذِينَ يَكْتُمُونَ مَا أَنْزَلْنَا مِنَ الْبَيِّنَاتِ وَ الْهُدَيٰ مِنْ بَعْدِ مَا بَيَّنَّاهُ لِلنَّاسِ فِي الْكِتَابِ أُولَئِكَ يَلْعَنُهُمُ اللَّهُ وَ يَلْعَنُهُمُ اللَّاعِنُونَ", who are "اللَّاعِنُونَ"?

Comment: or even more explicitly in alBaqara/161 "إِنَّ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا وَ مَاتُوا وَ هُمْ كُفَّارٌ أُولَئِكَ عَلَيْهِمْ لَعْنَةُ اللَّهِ وَ الْمَلَائِكَةِ وَ النَّاسِ أَجْمَعِينَ"

Comment: or in آیة‌المباهلة where Allah orders to the holy prophet to curse the liers in that case

Comment: or again explicitly in alMaedeh/78 "لُعِنَ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا مِنْ بَنِي إِسْرَائِيلَ عَلَيٰ لِسَانِ دَاوُودَ وَ عِيسَي ابْنِ مَرْيَمَ ذَلِكَ بِمَا عَصَوْا وَ كَانُوا يَعْتَدُونَ"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of sin.

Quran says there has already been for you an excellent pattern in Abraham. So this means that we should follow this pattern. He many times invited his people to monotheism by kindness. But they still insisted on Shirk and did not leave their idols and tried to kill prophet Ibrahim a.s.

A Muslims should disassociate and have animosity and hatred about Mushrik people (those who worship other than Allah like idol, Satan...). But hating is some different. We can disassociate one but still love him for guidance.

> There has already been for you an excellent pattern in Abraham and
>   those with him, when they said to their people, "Indeed, we are
>   disassociated from you and from whatever you worship other than Allah.
>   We have denied you, and there has appeared between us and you
>   animosity and hatred forever until you believe in Allah alone" except
>   for the saying of Abraham to his father, "I will surely ask
>   forgiveness for you, but I have not [power to do] for you anything
>   against Allah. Our Lord, upon You we have relied, and to You we have
>   returned, and to You is the destination. http://tanzil.net/#60:4

Prophet Muhammad SAWW did so also. he invited people many times and many of them accepted but some still did not accept and tried to kill prophet and made wars like Badr, Uhod and other wars and tried to kill Muslims. so then prophet made around 100 wars against them (although himself did not participate in all of them directly).

But it is important to distinguish between clear Shirk and Hidden Shirk. This applies only to clear Shirk. Because many of believers have hidden shirk:

> And most of them believe not in Allah except while they associate
>   others with Him.  http://tanzil.net/#12:106

But a Muslim who believes in Allah but still is sinner is different.

> There has certainly come to you a Messenger from among yourselves.
>   Grievous to him is what you suffer; [he is] concerned over you and to
>   the believers is kind and merciful. http://tanzil.net/#9:128

We should love and guide Muslims who are going astray and are sinner.

Comment: i think that meanings here have to be taken very carefully...because somewhere it also says that take no one else as a friend but Allah..which means not even muslims but we know that we are to take care of muslim friends and even non muslims relatives, neighbors, etc. In fact we are to show best character toward other people that's one message that one gets after studying prophet Muhammad PBUH life. So to me even a non Muslim deserves kindness..Just as prophet Muhammad Used to show toward all. Reconsider your opinion as it's not taking account practical life of prophet Muhammad and the rest.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer please read http://tanzil.net/#60:4 again and please note this verse is for when after many times of inviting them to monotheism they still insisted on Shirk. not from the first. anyway it is command of Quran. it is not made by me.

Comment: To understand the command of Quran we need to see everything hadiths (prophet's explanation) his practice of those commands, and lives of his companions. Yet i agree people who are against you and are sworn enemy and do not change their ways and appear to be the one who wont change then leaving them is the best. There is no need to like sworn enemies.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer yes all should be considered. but this does not cause ignoring the clear order of Quran for  disassociating them.

Comment: "disassociating and hatred among us" can be taken too far very easily if its meaning are taken by our standards. We need to look at how prophet followed this rule...for me to hate someone or disassociate is to never talk to the person, never help, and in fact make sure they get in trouble. But that is not what prophet DID. Yes command is clear but to practice that command we need role model who shows exactly how to do it..if we are to follow our own interpretations of that command we are most likely to end up as transgressors, especially in this case.

Comment: It's same as some people say that no muslim should take anyone as friends but Allah as friend. So muslim person shouldn't even take another muslim person as a friend. And that they are very confident in saying that. This however is very contradictory to how prophet and his companions lived..The contradiction is the result of our interpretation of word friend. Companions of prophets were better friends to each other than my dad could be to me or one i ever had. They really took care of each other in terms of both world and deen.